# Asp.net core Identity is not working with microservice

Tags: c#, microservices, asp.net-core-identity, ocelot

I am trying to implement Asp.net core identity with microservices. I created one microservice for identity. Migrated the identity and created the tables. I have created another project to display the values from the microservices. I am successfull in getting and posting the values with the microservices. But error is showing StatusCode 404 Not found while posting the values to identity microservice.

Below is the code for consuming Web API in Identity microservice by calling identity

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(User user)
    {
        HttpClient client = api.Initial(); 
        var postTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync<User>("identity", user);   
        postTask.Wait();
        var result = postTask.Result;
        if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

Below is the Post method of the identity API controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] UserViewModel user)
    {
        var idenUser = new MembershipUser();
        idenUser.Email = user.Email;
        idenUser.ChurchId = user.ChurchId;
        idenUser.IsDeleted = false;
        idenUser.PhoneNumber = user.MobileNo;
        idenUser.UserName = user.LoginName;
        var resultCreate = await userManager.CreateAsync(idenUser, 
         user.Password);

        if (resultCreate.Succeeded)
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created, user);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound, user);
        }
    }
```

Below is the ocelot.json API geteway code for the identity API

```
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/IdentityAPI",
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": "57608"
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/identity",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "POST" ]
},
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/api/IdentityAPI/{id}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "localhost",
      "Port": "57608"
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/identity/{id}",
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET", "PUT", "DELETE" ]
}
```

Comment: Could you post the error message so that we can understand your issue better ?

Comment: Calling other Web API in this project is working fine but when trying to call this identity Web API control is not entering into this web API and returns 404 Not found error.